# Comparing chars from command line arguments in C

Tags: c, string, getopt

I am trying to compare options that can be entered on the command line for my program. for option f a user can enter c or b.

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char *i;
    char *o;
    char *f;
    int c;
    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "i:o:f")) != -1)
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'i':
              i = optarg;
              break;
            case 'o':
              o = optarg;
              break;
            case 'f':
              f = optarg;
              break;
        }
    if(strcmp(f, "b") == 0){
        //execute code
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

__strcmp_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-avx2.S:115

115 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
```

Edit: I'm using Linux and running

```bash
gcc -g program.c program
gdb --args ./program -f b
```

Comment: What operating system are you using and what commands are you using to compile the program? Do you get any warnings or errors when you compile (if so, then add them to your question)?

Comment: Added some details to the question, no errors on compilation.

Comment: You need to tell `getopt()` that option `f` takes an argument with `"i:o:f:"`.

Comment: And since these are options you need to handle the case where `f` is not provided.  In that case you'd be calling `strcmp` with `f` uninitialized.

Comment: Good call, happy to give you credit if you submit an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here. One, `getopt()` needs to know that the `f` option takes an argument by adding the colon, like this:

```
getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:f:")
```

Second, `f` is being passed to `strcmp()` with no checking that `f` has a valid value. Because `getopt()` wasn't expecting an argument for the `f` option, `optarg` will be `NULL`, so `strcmp()` is likely the cause of the `SIGSEGV`.

It would be a good idea to initialize `i`, `o`, and `f` to `NULL` then check their values after calling `getopt()` to see if they point to a valid argument string before using them.

Answer (score 2):

1. If your program is called with `-f` it will crash as `strcmp()` expects two strings and the first argument is `NULL` which is not a string.  The is due to a missing guard on the call to `strcmp()`.
2. If your program requires `-f` to have an argument then the `optstring` should be `i:o:f:` (missing the `:` after `f`). This means `optarg` isn't `NULL` when processing the `f` option.
3. If your program is called without `-f` then the variable `f` remains uninitialized and the call to `strcmp()` is undefined behavior.  It happens to crash with `f == NULL` for me.
4. `getopt()` returns `?` for invalid options, I would say it's bad form to not handle that either explicitly or with a default.
5. Finally, I suggest using a `for(;;)` to avoid the assignment that is also an expression.  It's sufficiently error prune that gcc insist on wrapping the assignment in parenthesis.  This minimizes the scope of the variable `c`, and it's cleaner to handle all return values from `getopt()` in the same switch.  If you are allergic to `goto` use a flag instead.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *f = NULL;
    char *i = NULL;
    char *o = NULL;
    for(;;) {
        int c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:f:");
        switch (c) {
            case -1:
                goto done;
            case '?':
                // getopt generates error message
                break;
            case 'f':
                f = optarg;
                break;
            case 'i':
                i = optarg;
                break;
            case 'o':
                o = optarg;
                break;
        }
    }
done:
    printf("%sb\n", f && !strcmp(f, "b") ? "" : "not ");
    return 0;
}
```

and here is sample executions:

```
./a.out
not b
./a.out -f
./a.out: option requires an argument -- 'f'
not b
./a.out -f a
not b
./a.out -f b
b
```